# Intermittent issues RDPing into another machine on my LAN using 2Wire router/UVerse?

Tags: remote-desktop, lan

I just had AT&T UVerse installed and received a new 2Wire modem/router as part of that.  Previously I had DSL running a Linksys WRT54G w/ddwrt firmware.  I remote desktop (RDP) into another machine on my LAN quite often, but since the uverse install sometimes it will not connect to the other machine - i can't even ping it.  Usually a reboot of the client machine will solve the issue.  To get UVerse speeds to my house they used bonded copper pair from where the fiber cable stops ~3000ft from my house.  If I poke around in the 2Wire configuration screens I can see the two lines represented.  I'm wondering if that has something to do with my RDP issue?  Although I would think that would stop at the outside - and once inside my LAN it should not affect it.

So my questions are:

1. Does AT&T UVerse w/bonded pair and 2Wire modem/router cause any known issues with using RDP within a LAN?
2. If so any suggestions on how to solve my RDP issue?